# two dimensional vector access

Tags: c++, stl

whats the difference between these two access methods?

`nodes->at(235).push_back(NavigationNode(NULL,0,0));`

nodes[235].push_back(NavigationNode(NULL,0,0));

second one gives this compile error

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PathFinder::NavigationNode' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
```

i'm very confused about this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether `nodes` is a `vector` or a `vector *` (or an iterator).

If the first one compiles, then it must be a `vector *` (or an iterator).  In which case the second one would need to become:

```
(*nodes)[235].push_back(NavigationNode(NULL,0,0));
```

Note, however, that accessing via `operator[]` and via `at()` have different semantics.  The latter will do a bounds check.

Comment: It is `nodes->` in the first statement, so it should be `vector *`?

Comment: you are right it should be called as (*nodes)
compile error throws me off. thank you